# How to append a path to every file to be stored in array?

Tags: powershell

suppose i have an array

```
$f_attachments = @()
```

every file i have, i simply append to it

```
$f_attachments += $file
```

however, i would like to include the directory as well for every file saved in this array

in other words, instead of having to do something like this:

```
$f_attachments += $currentFolder\$file1
$f_attachments += $currentFolder\$file2
etc...
```

can i just append it at the array level?

```
$f_attachments = @($currentFolder)
```

---

**more explanation**

i have a HUGE script. i am appending files (i.e. `$f_attachments += $file1`  `$f_attachments += $file2`, etc...) to `$f_attachments` array at random parts of the script. this array is defined at the VERY BEGINNING

```
$f_attachments = @()
```

suppose my full script is like this:

```
$f_attachments = @()
if() 
{
do something...
$f_attachments += $currentFolder\$file1
}
else
{
do something...
$f_attachments += $currentFolder\$file2
}
....
```

as you can see, i added $currentFolder\ everytime i am adding a file to the array

i want something at the array definition level, here `$f_attachments = @()`

that will automatically append this `$currentFolder\`

in other words, an ideal solution would look like this:

```
$f_attachments = @($currentFolder\)
if() 
{
do something...
$f_attachments += $file1
}
else
{
do something...
$f_attachments += $file2
}
....
```

Comment: are you asking how you can just join 2 arrays together?

Comment: @ArcSet no, right now everywhere i have $f_attachments += $file, i have to add to it the location $f_attachments += $currentFolder\$file1 , $f_attachments += $currentFolder\$file2
etc... instead of having to follow this tedious process, cause its a LOT, i am looking for some way to just have the location or path $currentFolder added automatically to each file, or to eachtime a file is appended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop the array with a `foreach-object` and add the folder name.

The `|` means pipe. It takes the data from the input object and sends it to the next command in the pipe. This case `%{}` which is a alias for `Foreach-Object`.
You then are storing the output from `%{}` back into variable `$files`

```
$files = @("abc.txt","efg.txt","hij.txt","lmn.txt")

$files = $a | %{
    "FolderName\$_"
}

$files
```

EDIT : The post was updated with additional information.

So what you need here is a custom object that adds the folder to the name of each file added :

```
$Files = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Array = @()
    FolderName = ""
}
$Files | Add-Member -MemberType scriptmethod  -Name Files -Value {
    param([string]$File = "")
    if($File.Length -eq 0){
        return $this.Array
    }else{
        $this.Array += "$($this.FolderName)\$File"
    }
}


$Files.FolderName = "FolderHere"
$Files.Files("Test.txt")
$Files.Files("Test2.txt")
$Files.Files("Test3.txt")
$Files.Files("Test4.txt")
$Files.Files()
```

This returns

```
FolderHere\Test.txt
FolderHere\Test2.txt
FolderHere\Test3.txt
FolderHere\Test4.txt
```

We are creating a `new-object PSObject` with the properties **FolderName** which will store the folder name to add to the files. **Array** which will hold the final array object. **Files** which will be a `ScriptMethod` member that will add the folder to the name and if nothing is entered as a param will return the **Array** property

Comment: almost what i am looking for. except i cant define the files at once because they are randomly appended throughout the whole script depending on some conditional statements i have.  i am mainly looking for this part $files = | %{
    "FolderName\$_"
} and so now everywhere i have something like this $files += $file, it should append this to ti: FolderName\

Comment: I think you need to post a example of what you want in your main post. Post a working example of what you are doing. Then show what you would like to see as the output

Comment: i posted more explanation in my post